# accessing the controls on a webpage I have just opened

Tags: vb.net

I have a piece of code that opens a web page in my default browser (IE10).

```
Dim url As String
url = "http://www.google.com"
Process.Start(url)
```

How do I then pass a value to the text box on that page.  I am using google as an example.  I am using VS2013, VB and asp.net

Thanks

Comment: you should add the information you had written as comments to my answer to your question- it will help people to help you

Answer (score 0):

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9EJXzWasTq4) should give you all of the information that you need.  It is a tutorial on creating an automatic yahoo login from vb, but it will show you how to pass values to a textbox on a webpage, as well as working with other webpage controls.

NOTE: You will need to navigate to the page and view source to get the id of the controls